Simplifying calls to static methods of class template, when the type can be deduced from argument
I have a class template, and inside it a static method whose input argument is the class itself.
For example:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A( const T& t ) : val(t) {}
    static bool IsValid( const A<T>& a ) { return (bool)a.val; }

private:
    T val;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a( 5 );

    std::cout << A<int>::IsValid( a ) << "\n";   // <---
    return 0;
}

I find line 18 (marked with <---) very cumbersome to write over and over.
I wonder why I cannot call my method as A::IsValid( a ), given that the type T can be easily deduced from the input a?  Is there any way to write it differently so that this is possible?
The closest SO question I found was: Way to call a static method of a class template without specifying an instantiation?, but that question is inherently different since it has no arguments to deduce the type from.

because it cannot be deduced. A<T> has a method IsValid(A<T>) but the reverse is not true. IsValid(A<U>) can be method of some A<V>.

you can make it a free function

You can have arbitrary functions in class templates, yours just so happen to have a parameter with the same type as the class but that's not true for every function.

Why write A::IsValid(a) when you can write a.isValid() ?

@Botje: because in the real code, argument a is actually of type shared_ptr<A<T>>, and so the first thing that IsValid does is check the pointer itself for nullptr .

Why isValid is a static function? Just by its name I would suspect it is member function. Also arguments looks like exactly like this. So I wonder: why you've made this function static at all? Your comment above is a poor explanation. You way to address nullptr in an overkill.

No, it is not possible.
First consider that only CTAD (Class template argument deduction) deduces template arguments for class templates that are about to be constructed based on types of passed function arguments. Though, when you call the static method, no object is constrcuted.
Next consider that A<U> can be specialized to have a IsValid(const A<V>&) member. In other words, there is no 1 to 1 relation between the T on the type of the argument to IsValid(const A<T>&) and the T in A<T>::IsValid. For example:
template <> class A<double> {
    static bool IsValid(const A<int>& a) { return true; }
};

Now there would be no way to tell which instantitation of A is wanted when you call A::IsValid( A<int>{} ). Is this calling a method of A<int> or of A<double> ? Does it actually matter that this method is member of a class? Which brings me to..
You can write a free function:
 auto IsValid(const auto& a) { 
    return decltype(a)::IsValid(a);
 }

Or make it a non-static member function.
